# Fill 100% width with Bootsrap dropdown-toggle

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-4

I implemented the Bootstrap dropdown-toggle button on my site.
But it does not fill 100% width of the column it is in like I need it to.
Instead, it fills it to the width of the text/font.
If the font is larger, it will fill 100% width, but the text is outside the button.
As per the image below.

[image]

If I make the font smaller, it fills it to the size of the font.
As per image below.

[image]

How do I make the button fill 100% of the width of the col, regardlesss of the font size?
I have tried *width: 100%;* AND *display: block;*
I have also added the *btn-lg* class.

The dropdown next to it is using a regular  but I need to use a 



 for the left dropdown.

The CSS to add my own style to the button (and to try and set the size).

```
.my-dropdown-toggle-button {
            border-radius: 1px;
            font-size: 0.8em;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            background-color: #f9f9f9;
            height: 47px;
            border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
            color: #079E94;
            padding-left: 10px;
            background-image: linear-gradient(to right, 
                #f2f2f2,
                #f2f2f2 50%,
                transparent 50%,
                transparent);
            background-position: 100% 0;
            background-size: 200% 100%;
            transition: all .4s ease-in;
        }
```

And my HTML (showing layout as well)

```
<div class="container-fluid shop-page-main-container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3"><!-- Subnav content -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">

                    <div class="shop-page-subnav-box">
                        <h3>
                            Filter by Product
                        </h3>
                        <hr>

                        <div class="shop-page-subnav-box-dropdown">
                            <div class="dropdown">
                                <button class="dropdown-toggle my-dropdown-toggle-button btn-lg" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                                    By Product
                                    <span class="caret"></span>
                                </button>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-6 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12">
                    <div class="shop-page-subnav-box">
                        <h3>
                            Sort by Type
                        </h3>
                        <hr>
                        <select>
                            <option value="volvo"> By Type </option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why your code is not working, but what you want to achieve is just as simple as setting the button's width to 100%, or use the built-in class `.w-100`.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <h6 class="text-muted">
                Filter by Product
            </h6>
            <div class="dropdown">
                <button class="dropdown-toggle btn w-100" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
                    By Product
                </button>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">HTML</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">CSS</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <h6 class="text-muted">
                Sort by Type
            </h6>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option value>By Type</option>
                <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div> 
</div>
```

#### DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/j1b49fts/7/

[image]